# Ruby on Rails - how to correctly map and link to a new controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to create this controller:

```
  def calculate
    # Do some calculations here     


    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{head status}
    end
  end
```

and I have a HAML file in which I make my HTML and in there I want to link to something like this:

```
=link_to("stats" , controller_path_url)
```

where controller_path is a rake routes path that is shown.  My question is how do I make this sort of uniquely named controller function to be mapped and show its path when I do rake routes? Is there something I have to do in routes.rb? What should I change there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do smth like following in your `routes.rb` file:

> match 'calculate' => 'controller_name#calculate'

then run:

> bundle exec rake routes

and see your path.

It should be `calculcate_path` for path and `calculate_url` for full path.

Comment: I use 'bundle exec' because 'rake' command don't work without it in console. It just give you an opportunity to see list of your pathes.

Comment: For what it's worth the rake command works fine for me in my console without bundle exec. The route should be added as soon as it's in the file, no need to run rake routes if you know your path is right. It can be helpful to run it just to check everything worked as expected though

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify your routes.rb file. I suggest you check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html , it's really extremely helpful.